# Can't position div after another div with position fixed

Tags: html, css, jsx

I have a div which has a position of fixed. There is a div under it, which I am having hard time positioning. Here's my JSX markup:

```
<div>
   <div style={topBar}>
     REAL TIME AIR QUALITY INDEX
   </div>
   <div style={infoDiv}>
     Lorem Ipsum
   </div>
</div>
```

And here's my styling:

```
const topBar = {
  width: '100%',
  background: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.1)',
  position: 'fixed',
  padding: '10px',
  textAlign: 'center',
  fontWeight: '800',
  background: 'yellow'
}

const infoDiv = {
  background: 'red',
  marginTop: '100px'
}
```

My problem is that instead of `topBar` staying fixed to the top and `infoDiv` coming down 100px, the `infoDiv` stays on top and `topBar` comes down.

Here's a picture:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to identify the `top` and `left` of the `topBar` to make it remains upside and change the `maginTop` of the `infoDiv`

```
const topBar = {
  width: '100%',
  background: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.1)',
  position: 'fixed',
  top: '0', 
  left: '0', 
  padding: '10px',
  textAlign: 'center',
  fontWeight: '800',
  background: 'yellow'
}

const infoDiv = {
  background: 'red',
  marginTop: '10px'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think all you need to do is set the position of the yellow `topBar` by using `top: 0` and `left: 0`. That should push it to the top of your screen.

Answer (score 0):

Take away the margin-top from the infoDiv styling and try adding margin-bottom to the topBar styling.